# Google AdSense ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Tags: adsense

My website has just been approved by AdSense, and I tried to put some basic display ads on the site.
I've set up the ad, and pasted the HTML Code in my project.

When I visit the website, the console says:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID (at adsbygoogle.js:1)`

I thought it was a problem of my website, but when I try to manually open the adsbygoogle JS, my browser also says `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`.

Anyone knows what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was because of my Windows hosts file... Some program I've used earlier, blocked a lot of Hosts through it.